# How can I change size of partition that is part of zpool

Tags: linux, filesystems, partition, zfs

I have one 100GB partition that is part of ZFS storage pool. How can I notify ZFS about new partition size after resizing the partition to 200GB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change size of your partition using your favourite partitioning tool.

   `cfdisk` and `cgdisk` have simple interface that allows creation, resizing and deletion of partitions.
2. Make sure the new partition size was acknowledged by Linux. `lsblk` will show you table of disks and their partitions.

   If not, run `partprobe` to refresh all partition lists. GPT-partitioned disks (maybe only on older kernels) usually need this.
3. Use `zpool online -e` (`-e` stands for *expand*):

   ```
   zpool online -e poolName /dev/sdxX
   ```

   You do not have to execute `zpool offline` before that.
4. (Optional) Adjust quotas if you want to. If you don't have set quota, underlying volumes will automatically get the new size.